# Why is there no logfile for my privoxy?

Tags: proxy, log

There are two lines in `/etc/privoxy/config`:

```
logdir /var/log/privoxy
logfile logfile
```

The command `curl -x "127.0.0.1:8118"  https://www.yahoo.com` has been executed many times.

```
cat /var/log/privoxy/logfile
```

Why is there nothing in the log file `/var/log/privoxy/logfile`?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `debug=<some value>` for example `debug=1` in your `/etc/privoxy/config`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Debugging](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#DEBUGGING) docs section you should set `debug` in the `/etc/privoxy/config`, i.e. add

```
debug 1 
debug 2 
debug 4
```

You can find the meaning of these numbers in the linked docs.